# Vector or Synchronized LinkedList?Which is better to use?

Tags: java, collections

I think this is very interesting topic. In your choice, then which is better between Vector or synchronized LinkedList?

Synchronized for LinkedList:

```
LinkedList linkedlist=new LinkedList();
List synchronizedlist= Collections.synchronizedList.(linkedlist);
```

Comment: Vector is very old class so, use a list.

Comment: You'll find that in most real-life scenarios the answer is: neither. Usually you need higher level synchronization.

Comment: The other important difference is that if you create a synchronized list like that,  you must make absolutely sure that no-one has access to the value of the `linkedlist` variable directly, as `Collections.synchronizedList()` wraps the original list, any changes to either are reflected in the other.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is their implementation which causes different performance for different operations.

Vector is similar with ArrayList, but it is synchronized.

Syncronized LinkedList is implemented as a double linked list. Its performance on add and remove is better than Arraylist, but worse on get and set methods.

Comment: It is better to use synchronized LinkedList. The returned list is synchronized, but still the original list is not synchronized. When non-synchronized version is required in programming, the original can be used. In the above snippet of code, in a multithreaded environment yourList can be used and non-synchronized myList can be used non-multithreaded environment. If vector is chosen, we cannot get a non-synchronized version

Comment: Yes it is depend on your requirement for environment

Comment: @QuanNguyen That's plain wrong. Once you wrapped it in a synchronized wrapper, you must **never** use the unwrapped list instance again.